# In Sql Server, how to convert binary strings to binary?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, binary

I have some data in string format that represents binary data (e.g. '0x0002').  Is there some function or trick where I can convert these from literal strings to binary?  That is, I want '0x0002' to become 0x0002, and SELECT CAST('0x0002' AS BINARY(20)) obviously won't do that.  I did come up with some painfully slow process that involves building up SQL Statements and assigning them to a variable and executing that (e.g. "EXEC (@Query)"), but I'm looking for something where I don't have to do that.

If it helps, here is a sample table that you can test this on:

```
CREATE TABLE #T (BinaryString VARCHAR(100))
INSERT INTO #T VALUES('0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000002') -- Binary = the integer 2
INSERT INTO #T VALUES('0x000000000000000000000000000000000000007B') -- Binary = the integer 123
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Older code, SQL 7, sp_hexadecimal](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/104829)

[SQL 2005 (+ 2000 maybe), master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/06/11/converting-a-hex-string-to-a-varbinary-or-vice-versa/)

[SQL 2008, native](http://decipherinfosys.wordpress.com/2008/07/31/sql-server-2008-converting-binary-and-character-values/)